# JSON.parse(dt) doesn't work at all, give all the errors it can imagine

Tags: json, node.js, actionscript-3

I have this code at server side (nodejs):

```
socket.on('data', function(dt){
    var rdata = dt;
    var msg = JSON.parse(rdata);
    broadcast(msg);
});
```

Also I tried this way: `var msg = JSON.parse(dt);`

dt gets either:

```
{"chat":"hey","nickname":"nick_name"}    OR 
'{"chat":"hey","nickname":"nick_name"}'
```

Also I have this at the client side (AS3), tried both:

```
var msg = JSON.stringify({nickname: nname.text, chat: input_txt.text});   OR
var msg = "'" + JSON.stringify({nickname: nname.text, chat: input_txt.text}) + "'";
```

That is what console gives:

```
undefined:1
{"chat":"hey","nickname":"nick_name"}
                                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
DEBUG: Program node app exited with code 8
```

Also in some other situations, it gives all kinds of messages.

Just have no idea what is going on.
BTW, also tried JSONStream, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unexpected token at the end of data string, is some ghost symbol that is not a white space. trim() doesn't work, so to substring the last symbor works. This is AS3 symbol, so we have to keep it. First you save this symbol in the new variable. the you erase this symbol from the line. After that you can parse the string. work with it.

```
undefined:1
{"chat":"hey","nickname":"nick_name"}
                                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
DEBUG: Program node app exited with code 8
```

When you finish working with it, stringify the object, then add ghost symbol to the end and send over the socket. Without this symbol AS3 will not parse the data.

I don't know why is that, but that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of socket exactly are you using? If you are using a websocket you might have already received an object as a response (I think most frameworks do so). If you are using plain net.socket you might be receiving a buffer or the data in chunks and not all at once. This seems like an appropriate fix for that situation:

```
var buffer;
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    buffer += data;
});
socket.on('end', function() {
    var object = JSON.parse(buffer);
});
```

Comment: I use require("net"), and it seems that I get a buffer, when I console.log(dt) I get **<buffer .some numbers. >** so it is closed and all the data received. if I send the message to the API in the raw format I also get the JSON string without loosing anything. **{"chat":"hey","nickname":"nick_name"} OR 
'{"chat":"hey","nickname":"nick_name"}'** And also I have to keep the connection alive.